# How to use sort for sorting file in BASH?

Tags: bash, sorting

I have to sort file. When I use sort, it takes only first word in every line. For example. I have these words in line.

**able a abundance around accelerated early acting following ad**

I execute

**sort file.txt**

Output is:

**able a abundance around accelerated early acting following ad**

If I have just one column, sort works. What is the problem?

Comment: From the `man` pages: `sort - sort lines of text files`.  `sort` works on **lines**, not columns.

Comment: I know, but my sort works on columns **not lines**.

Comment: Is your real file a one-liner too? if you have multiple lines of input, how do you want to have the output organized?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
tr " " "\n" < file.txt | sort | tr "\n" " " > newfile.txt
```

Output to newfile.txt:

```
a able abundance accelerated acting ad around early following
```

Comment: I can't create new files. I tried to use sed and it helps. But I have problems with numebers. How could I avoid sorting numbers (for eaxmple date)?

Comment: @user3465780 sort has lots of options, check out the man page `man sort`

Answer (score 1):

A few options for you:

To sort the words in a line, you can use `sed` to replace spaces with new lines then pipe that to `sort`:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file.txt | sort
```

To sort on a specific column use `awk` to print the column then pipe that to `sort`:

```
awk {print $2} | sort
```

I've used this a lot working with data files, and I have yet to find a way to get the whole line after the sort.

Comment: I used this! :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put each word on a separate line:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file.txt | sort | paste -d" " -s
```

```
a able abundance accelerated acting ad around early following
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to sort each line in a a multi line file, the following one-liner can do it for you

```
python2 -c"print '\n'.join(' '.join(sorted(l.split())) for l in open('FILE'))"
```

If the above looks useful, you can augment your  `~/.bashrc` with

```
csort(){ python2 -c"print '\n'.join(' '.join(sorted(l.split()))for l in open('$1'))";}
```

and later use it like in

```
csort FILE
```

The machinery of the `python` command is best explained exploding the command line like this

```
with open('FILE') as f:                 # f is a file object
    for line in f:                      # iterating on a f.o. returns lines
        words = line.split()            # by default splits on white space
        print " ".join(sorted(words))   # sorted returns a sorted list
                                        # ' '.join() joins the list elements with spaces
```